# E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android App is working fine without any crash but I don't know why I am getting these errors in Android monitor.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try to disable Instant Run.

Comment: As I disable Instant Run, Android studio recommends to enable it for handling production issues.

Comment: I see, but Instant Run may cause Your error sometimes. I can't tell more without more details.

Comment: Could you tell me, Is it okay to go live with these errors without disabling Instant Run? Because I am launching my first app and I have no idea of production.

Comment: I think it's OK to go live without disabling Instant Run. Instant Run is Android Studio feature, allows faster build, install during development. This is new feature and it may have bugs. But please check user will not have these when run release apk. Uninstall app from device, make release apk. Then install apk using adb install or put apk to device (Downloads or somewhere), and tap on it and install. Run app and check logcat for errors. If You have these when running app (not debug from Android Studio, run from device by tap icon) I'd fix these before do live.